# Rails expected, got Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to get a id from a array and when get it shows this on the action add Order.new

> Color(#70131258622840) expected, got Array(#70131401174240)

someone have any idea why?

**product model**

```
has_many :colorships
has_many :colors, through: :colorships
```

**color model**

```
has_many :colorships
has_many :products, :through => :colorships
```

**product controller**

```
def new
  Product.New
  @dropdown = @product.colors.collect { |co| [co.name, co.id] } 
end

def show
  Product.find(params[:id])
  color = product.colors.select { |i| [i.id] } 
end

def add
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if product
    color = product.colors.select { |i| [i.id] } 
    if order.nil? # create new order
      order = Order.new
      order.product = product
      order.color =   color        
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: showing the whole backtrace helps others to see where the problem exists, so I encourage to show the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
color = product.colors.select { |i| [i.id] }
```

this line is giving you an array of colors, not a color. This would be more natural

```
color = product.colors.select { |i| i.id }
```

but `select` gives you an array as well, even of one element in this case. `find` gives you just the element you want or `nil` instead

```
color = product.colors.find { |i| i.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need array of ids. you can also get by `product.colors.ids`.

This will return array of ids of color.